# WordPress custom query for multiple meta key and meta value for search

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, select, meta-query

I have Three DropDown with multi-selection. Also used AJAX for getting the data using WP_Query.

Process: If I am select first OR any DropDown from the page then it will return a result. Then select the second DropDown then it will set the "AND" relation to getting the result means common result should return.

I have faced an issue with setting the relation between different selections.

Please help me!

Here is the code: Filter.js

```
    var test1 = [];
    var test2 = [];
    var test3 = [];

var ajaxurl = ajaxfilter.ajax_url;
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('#domaine').on('change', function() {
        test1 = jQuery(this).val();

        if (test1 !== null) {
            var data = {
                action: 'get_fill_portfolio',
                opt_domaine: test1,
                opt_status: test2,
                opt_fond: test3
            }
            jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                jQuery('.load-state').html(response);
            });
        }

    });

    jQuery('#status').on('change', function() {
        test2 = jQuery(this).val();


        if (test2 !== null) {
            var data = {
                action: 'get_fill_portfolio',
                opt_domaine: test1,
                opt_status: test2,
                opt_fond: test3

            }
            jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                jQuery('.load-state').html(response);
            });
        }

    });

    jQuery('#fond').on('change', function() {

        test3 = jQuery(this).val();


        if (test3 !== null) {
            var data = {
                action: 'get_fill_portfolio',
                opt_domaine: test1,
                opt_status: test2,
                opt_fond: test3

            }
            jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                jQuery('.load-state').html(response);

            });
        }

    });
```

Functions.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_get_fill_portfolio', 'get_fill_portfolio');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_fill_portfolio', 'get_fill_portfolio');
// Select Dropdown List
function get_fill_portfolio() 
{   

   /* check_ajax_referer( 'load_states', 'security' );

    $return = array();
    echo $return;
    wp_die(); // You missed this too*/

    $all_portfolio = [];
    global $post;

    $opt_domaine = $_POST['opt_domaine'];
    $opt_status = $_POST['opt_status'];
    $opt_fond = $_POST['opt_fond'];


    $string = rtrim(implode(',', $opt_domaine), ',');
    $string1 = rtrim(implode(',', $opt_status), ',');
    $string2 = rtrim(implode(',', $opt_fond), ',');


    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'stm_portfolio',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'orderby'        => 'menu_order',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',

           array(
              'relation' => 'AND',
              'mnf_domaine' =>  array(
                'key' => 'mnf_domaine',
                'value' => $string,
                'compare' => 'IN'
                ),
            ),

            array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
            'mnf_status' => array(
                'key' => 'mnf_status',
                'value' => $string1,
                'compare' => 'IN'
                ),
            ),  

          array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                'mnf_fond' => array(
                'key' => 'mnf_fond',
                'value' => $string2,
                'compare' => 'IN'
                )
             )
            )
    );

$query_s = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $query_s->have_posts() ) { 

        while ( $query_s->have_posts() ) : $query_s->the_post();
            $all_portfolio[] = [
                'name' => get_the_title( $post->ID),
                'mnf_site_web'  => get_field('mnf_site_web', $post->ID),
                'link'   => get_permalink($post->ID),
                'mnf_domaine'  => get_field('mnf_domaine', $post->ID),
                'mnf_status'  => get_field('mnf_status', $post->ID),
                'mnf_fond'  => get_field('mnf_fond', $post->ID),
                'img_url'  => get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post->ID, 'full' )
            ];
        endwhile;

        if ( $all_portfolio ) : 
            $domaine = get_field_object('mnf_domaine'); 
            $status = get_field_object('mnf_status'); 
            $fond = get_field_object('mnf_fond'); 

        endif;  

?>

 <div class="logo-filter">
        <div class="row">
            <?php foreach ( $all_portfolio as $portfolio ) : ?>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <a href="<?=$portfolio['link']?>" target="" class="logo-link">
                        <img alt="<?=$portfolio['name']?>" src="<?=$portfolio['img_url']?>">
                    </a>    
                    </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
        wp_reset_query();   
        }
    }

?>
```

It should be give result when I am searching from any dropdown with multiple selection.

Currently, I have three Drop-Down. So here, I want to implement search functionality as per multi-selection from Drop-Down. When I use `'relation' => 'AND'` Then i have to select three Drop-Down and then it is return results. So i have tried to use the `'relation' => 'OR'` So it is return all result.

So here i am confuse for using Relation between Three Drop-Down with Multi-Selection.

I want to set Query like

```
AND ( 
  ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'mnf_domaine' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value IN ('media', 'media1') ) 
  AND
  ( mt1.meta_key = 'mnf_status' AND mt1.meta_value IN ('test1', 'test2') ) 
  OR 
  ( mt2.meta_key = 'mnf_fond' AND mt2.meta_value IN ('') )
```

Thank You!

Comment: @sayed Mohd Ali, Can you please give me suggestion?

Comment: I will glad to but your question is not clear what you are trying to do, you need to be more clear with an example. what are you trying to achieve and what you are getting right now.

Comment: @SayedMohdAli, Okay, Let me explain in same post.